# How to display total count in geom_text

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have been trying to produce a count of Booking made and no booking made. Below is the code that I have used. It is giving me full count (sum) across all days. How can I amend my code to give me count across stacked graph that is. I want count of booking made and count of non booking made.

```
p <- ggplot(swiss,aes(x=as.factor(No.of.days.request.took)))
p + geom_bar(aes(fill=as.factor(Booking_new))) + 
    geom_text(aes(label=..count..),
              vjust=1,stat='count',
              position = "stack")
```

[image]

Comment: Should be fine to just add that to the `aes` of `geom_text`. `group = Booking_new`

Comment: Thank you Dave. That helped.:)

Comment: I have now managed to get the count label on stacked graph but I would like to see the percentage of counts across each day grouped by booking. How can I achieve that? I have used the following code but it doesn't seem to produce the result that I want.

Comment: p<-ggplot(swiss,aes(x=as.factor(No.of.days.request.took)))
p+geom_bar(aes(fill=as.factor(Booking_new)))+geom_text( aes(label= ((..count..)/sum(..count..)), group=as.factor(Booking_new)),vjust=1,stat='count',position = "stack")

Comment: I would either edit your question, or open up a new question.  Either way, it would be very helpful if you provided an example of your data frame.